# Adjusted repeat with one minute alarmmanager turns into 5 minutes

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

Firstly, I'm sorry for my english.
I am using alarmManager, but i have a problem about it.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent;

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,0,intent,0);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);`
```

I'm using this code to start alarm that repeats every minute. Alarm that run first time runs perfect, but repeat time turns into 5 minutes after a while, and goes on in this way. What can cause this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method setInExactRepeating to conserve battery power, but the method is inexact like it says. In the documentation for AlarmManager: "As of API 19, all repeating alarms will be inexact and subject to batching with other alarms regardless of their stated repeat interval." This has also been my experience using the AlarmManager setInExactRepeating method.

**Please use the AlarmManager method *setRepeating* if you need the time to be exact:**

```
 setRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation);
```

*type*: One of ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC, or RTC_WAKEUP.

*triggerAtMillis*:  time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).

*intervalMillis*:   interval in milliseconds between subsequent repeats of the alarm.

*operation*:    Action to perform when the alarm goes off; typically comes from 
IntentSender.getBroadcast().

You can find more info here if needed: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. My problem is that my alarm is working fine about 1 minute that is not exact, but alarm's interval be about 5 minutes after a while. As if alarm is changed to 5 minutes by someone.

Comment: I understand.  You need to use setRepeating method, not setInExactRepeating.

Comment: I changed setInExactRepeating to setRepeating,but it doesn't work I expected.

Comment: Hmm, I assume you are saying the alarm interval still drifts to 5 minutes?  Please try changing setRepeating parameters to this: alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, alarmTime.getTimeInMillis(), repeatIntervalMilliseconds, pendingIntent);  

The variable repeatIntervalMilliseconds should be 60*1000.  Please notice several of these parameters are different than what you were using.